# Working with an array of structs in Julia

Tags: arrays, struct, julia

I have a mutable struct defined in Julia, when I am unable to store data inside it. My struct is as follows:

```
mutable struct MPData{T}
    MPType::Char
    ConstModelType::Char
    MPCoords::Array{T}
    MPVol::T
    MPInitVol::T
    MPMass::T
    MPNodes::Array{UInt32}
    MPEls::Array{UInt32}
    NumStiffMatEntries::UInt32
    BasisFns::Array{T}
    BasisFnsDerivs::Array{T}
    PrevDefGrad::Array{T}
    CurrentDefGrad::Array{T}
    CauchyStress::Vector{T}
    PrevElasticStrain::Vector{T}
    CurrentElasticStrain::Vector{T}
    MatConsts::MatParams
    PointForces::Array{T}
    Displacement::Array{T}
end
```

The Initialization of the Array of the struct is as below: `MPDataArray = Array{MPData{Float32},1}(undef, TotalNumMP)` where `TotalNumMP` is the length of the array. But, when I try to actually populate the struct with data I am getting the error  `LoadError: UndefRefError: access to undefined reference`. The code for populating the struct is:

```
for MPNum in 1:TotalNumMP
     MPDataArray[MPNum].MPType = 'M'
end
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Unless it is strictly necessary, you should avoid having abstract field types in your struct, for performance reasons, and also for correctness. `Array{Int32}` is an abstract type. If you know that you will always use a 1D array, then use `Array{Int32, 1}` or `Vector{Int32}` (these are the same). If you need the dimensionality to vary, then use a type parameter, like you did with `T`, so that, e.g. `BasisFns::Array{T, N}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created an `Array` with your `MPData{T}` struct as its element type and allocated memory for `TotalNumMP` elements, but no actual instances of the struct were created. That's called an *uninitialized* array, indicated by the `undef`.

If the struct was immutable and uses no pointers (isbitstype), you could still index the array, but all the values would be random garbage.

However, you had a mutable struct which necessarily uses a pointer, so it is not an isbitstype. In that case, Julia does not allow you to access that element as if there were an instance there (`MPDataArray[MPNum]`), because otherwise you would have a dangling pointer, something so dangerous they won't even let you have it as random garbage. The only thing you're allowed to do with an uninitialized element is assign a proper instance:

```
MPDataArray[MPNum] = MPData(...)
```

It appears that you want to make an array with actual instances, then modify the instances. In that case you should define a way to make a dummy value, like:

```
Base.zero(::Type{MPData{T}}) where T = MPData(...)
```

Then you can make a fully initialized array of dummy values with:

```
zeros(MPData{T}, TotalNumMP)
```

Comment: So basically I have to initialize the struct with a constructor and not using individual struct variables?

Comment: Oh excuse me for that now-deleted comment, I misread "struct" as "array" in your comment, yes every struct instance has to be made by a constructor, THEN you may mutate its fields if it were a mutable struct.

Comment: For example, you could make an array with `[MPData(...), MPData(...), MPData(...)]`, or if you had some sort of iterables (e.g. Array) of field values, you could broadcast the constructor over them: `MPData.(field1Array, field2Array, field3Array, ...)`

Comment: For performance reasons you might want to consider `StructArrays.jl` for this data structure. The way to handle it will be identical to this answer

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel I've read about that package but don't have much experience with it, my impression was that the performance benefits come from the possible use of SIMD on arrays of small isbits fields. However, in this case most of the fields are Arrays. Are there other sources of performance benefits?

Comment: The point is that isbits are aligned nicely in memory and you do not need to jump around.  We do not know whether `T` in qustion is isbit, but I guess it could be. Anyway the first thing is to avoid `abstract` types